# How to redirect all POST requests via .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I want all POST requests that are made by form submitting or via AJAX to be redirected to one single file (e.g.`postManager.php`) which is located outside the root directory, like this:

```
_post
| ---postManager.php
|
public_html // root directory
| ---file_one.php
| ---file_two.php
```

The request might go from `file_one.php` via `$.post("file_two.php");` for example, and what's required for it is to go to the `postManager.php` anyway with all the `$_POST` data so it can be handled. Considering that it's shared hosting, I have access only to `.htaccess` and from here I want to make it.
So far, I've tried something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/..? <-- and that's where I'm lost
```

Will appreciate any help regards to this with clear explanation!

Comment: So set the `url` property of the ajax call to `postManager.php`

Comment: You could essentially create a php file and send ajax request to tell it where to send the data theres no need for this to be something in the .htaccess

Comment: @JosephWilliamson ok then how to set `_post/postManager.php` as destination if it's outside the root folder (public_html) from where tha ajax its actually going?

Comment: you can set an absolute url for the ajax request "https://mydomain/postManager.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...actually, after a certain number of tries I ended up with that code solution:

So, here's my post ajax which is made from any file in any project folder directing to the root folder or anyway:

```
$.post( "/" , { variable : "myVar" } );
```

In this case it goes to the `mydomain.com` but it actually does not, because it's halfway caught by .htaccess redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ postManager.php [QSA,L=307]
```

postManager.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

And if I request response by `.done(function(data){console.log(data)});` it gives it to me:

```
Array ( [variable] => Myvar )
```

Does anyone have any extra suggestions or comments regards to this code, because I'm not sure whether it's correct and safe, and whether it works exactly the way I decribed it..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax request should point to the location of `postManager.php`. You don't need to modify the `.htaccess` file for this.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'post/postManager.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {}
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: It should do, afterall its basically what is said in the first comment

Comment: but it's a whole point not to mention the actual destination file in ajax + this way I can't direct request to the directory outside `public_html`
see what I mean?

Comment: It's an unconventional way of doing this but I see what you mean. You are probably worried about people snooping around with that file. There are many ways of fixing this but redirecting isn't the best one :(

Comment: @BenGarb I kinda agree with you here, but I think the .htaccess redirection is still somehow safe way to hide any location of the executable files, isn't it?

Comment: @Bohdan There is no way for a user who does not have access to your server to see any php code you have written however your main concern should be someone using this to send data to your server but as long as you use prepared statements and escape the input you shouldnt have to worry too much

Comment: I'm assuming this file get executed from an admin part of the site (Where an admin user is loggedin), specially If you are doing operations that call the Database. If you are doing this, then you don't have to worry.

Comment: @JosephWilliamson Thumbs up to that